# Data model for tracking currency in a safe

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am attempting to design an application that tracks currency and recent transactions in a safe.  I am using entity-framework code-first in a wpf desktop application.

The first goal is to be able to track whats currently in the safe. For example - 87 Ones, 55 Twos, 76 fives, etc..

The second goal is to be able to track recent deposits/withdrawals into/out of the safe. For example - user X deposited 5 ones, 10 fives on 1/1/14.

Is the following a reasonable entity framework data model to accomplish this?

```
class Safe
{
    public int SafeId { get; set; }

    public CurrencySet Totals { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SafeTransaction> SafeTransactions { get; set; }
}

class CurrencySet
{
    public int CurrencySetId { get; set; }

    public int Ones { get; set; }
    public int Twos { get; set; }
    public int Fives { get; set; }
    public int Tens { get; set; }
    public int Twenties { get; set; }
    public int Fifties { get; set; }
    public int Hundreds { get; set; }
}

class SafeTransaction
{
    public int SafeTransActionId { get; set; }

    public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public CurrencySet Currency { get; set; }

    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }

}

enum TransactionType
{
    Withdrawal,
    Deposit
}
```

One concern I have is tracking non-US currency. Not a requirement currently, but maybe in the future.

Comment: I don't think that this code is sufficiently complete to be reviewable.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because improving data model design changes what the code does; code review answers normally improve *how* code does what it does, without changing *what* it does.

Comment: Where would the more appropriate place for a question like this be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *One concern I have is tracking non-US currency. Not a requirement currently, but maybe in the future.*

You're right to be concerned about the flexibility of your approach: what would `Twos` return in a currency that doesn't have toonies?

Taking future considerations into account, I think you need to re-think your model.

---

> #### CurrencySet

By modeling the `CurrencySet` entity the way you have, you've pretty much hard-coded the currency paper's nominal values:

> ```
> class CurrencySet
> {
>     public int CurrencySetId { get; set; }
>
>     public int Ones { get; set; }
>     public int Twos { get; set; }
>     public int Fives { get; set; }
>     public int Tens { get; set; }
>     public int Twenties { get; set; }
>     public int Fifties { get; set; }
>     public int Hundreds { get; set; }
> }
> ```

I'd suggest something like this:

```
public class Currency
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string CultureName { get; set; } // for number formats

    public virtual ICollection<CurrencyExchangeRate> CurrencyExchangeRates { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CurrencyPaper> CurrencyPapers { get; set; }
}

public class CurrencyExchangeRate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public int ReferenceCurrencyId { get; set; }
    
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }

    public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }
    public virtual Currency ReferenceCurrency { get; set; }
}

public class CurrencyPaper
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }

    public decimal NominalValue { get; set; }
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
    public int YearIssued { get; set; }

    public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can detect currency paper with consecutive serial numbers if you want, and your `Safe` can contain papers in many currencies, and calculate the total value in $USD, CDN$, €EUR or ¥YEN, given the exchange rate for $USD as a reference currency.

Granted, me putting `SerialNumber`, `Issuer` and `YearIssued` in there is pushing it, but it makes a point: this model is much closer to the actual real-world objects - an approach with its own pros and cons.

---

> #### Safe

Doing this turns your `Safe` into an actual *safe* that *literally contains* money - it also means the calculating the `Totals` is a *method* that has nothing to do in the data itself:

```
public class Safe
{
    int Id { get; set }

    //...

    public virtual ICollection<CurrencyPaper> CurrencyPapers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TransactionLog> TransactionLogs { get; set; }
}
```

---

> #### SafeTransaction

It's really a *log entry* more than the *transaction* itself: I think I'd call it `TransactionLog` though.

Now what your code is doing, is logging the number of individual `CurrencyPaper` instances that were involved in a transaction. To do this with the approach I'm suggesting, you might want to break the transaction logs in two tables for full details: one with "header", another with "details" (enabling tracking of individual `CurrencyPaper` instances) - but that's certainly overkill. You could also just track the total amount deposited/withdrawn, given a `Currency`.

---

- Navigation properties should be `virtual`
- Be consistent about FK properties - your `SafeTransaction` doesn't have them.
- Naming is ok - although I prefer the entity key to be called `Id`.